# How to print escape sequence when list type conversion str type

Tags: python

For example, I have a list

```py
l = ['\n']
```

conversion to str

```py
s = str(l)
```

it's output

```
['\n']
```

I want to print a linefeed. What should I do.
I try to remove `'['` and `"'"`

```py
print(s.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",""))
```

It's have no effect.

Comment: You need to print the string inside the list, not the list representation. So you should be doing `print(l[0])`, or if you have more than one item, iterating over the list using a loop to print each item.

Comment: What should happen if the list has more than one element? I can think of three different solutions, but they would all give different results in that situation. (Namely, the two solutions @shriakhilc mentioned plus `''.join(l)`.) It might also help to know, where is the list coming from?

Comment: I have a 40*40 list to print time after time in a loop. I dont want to used the loop again.

Answer (score -1):

**Solve.**
when list to str,It's Why print `\n`.instead of linefeed. beacause it not conversion a linefeed,but a `\\n` character.so,just use `\n` replace `\\n`.

```py
s.replace("\\n","\n")
```

Comment: This is not true when, as given in your question, the list is created with `l = ['\n']`.

Comment: Now, yes, you do create this problem when you use `s = str(l)`, but you shouldn't be doing that in the first place; the comments already include better suggestions in how to avoid it.